Fast shortest-path address-friendly routing software
I'm working on a project to try to find the shortest route time between two different addresses. I wanted to use OSMnx, but calculating just between two points took an hour, which is not something my project can manage. I need something that can be relatively efficient for over 300 addresses, is useable in Python, is free, and can take in string addresses, including apartment addresses. Does anyone know of such a software?

"but calculating just between two points took an hour" Provide a minimal reproducible code snippet. OSMnx can easily handle this use case, so this sounds like an implementation problem.
